# How to make a Django view that does both a GET and POST?

Tags: django, django-views

I am creating instances of my Django model object: myObject.

I have already setup a Django Form Wizard to allow the user to create new instances of myObjects.

I have already setup a view that allows the user to "drilldown" on myObject using a GET like this: "myWebsite.com/?objID=5"

After the last step of the Form Wizard, I redirect the user to "myWebsite.com/?objID="
So far so good. It works. However I have two new requirements:

1. At the top of this drilldown page, I want it to say "Here is your newly created Object" if I was just redirected to this page by the Form Wizard.
2. Regardless of weather I came to this drilldown page from the Form Wizard or by any other means, I want the URL to remain the same as I have explained above.

Requirement #2 Necessitates that I use a POST so as not to change the URL. But the original URL requires a GET. So it seems I need to do a GET and a POST on the same page. How can I do that? Am I misunderstanding something? Is there a better way for me to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: <form method="POST" action="myWebsite.com/?objID=5">

Answer (score 3):

You don't actually need to make both GET and POST requests simultaneously. What you're missing is that a POST request can actually have GET parameters as well as POST ones. So, as matino points out in the comments, this is perfectly valid:

```
<form method="POST" action="myWebsite.com/?objID=5">
```

In your view, `request.GET` will contain `{'objID': 5}` and `request.POST` will contain whatever is submitted in your form.

Comment: I need to do this from within the done() function of my form wizard. Can you please show me how to alter the python code within my done() function to accomplish this POST? Currently my done() function looks like this: 

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        newObjID = createObj()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/?objID=%s' % str(newObjID ))

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I use:

```
# views.py
def api(request):
    params = request.POST.copy()
    params.update(request.GET)
    # now params has both get and post params merged
```

Comment: Nice. even in 2022 this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make an http request that is both a POST and a GET request. Trying to do so is bad and will break the interweb.

It goes against [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-5) (the w3c specification for http). http provides for a single method which must be one of 'OPTIONS', 'GET', 'HEAD', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'TRACE', 'CONNECT'

Although this is a principle often ignored by developers, GET is designed to retrieve a resource from a server, specifically, without changing the state of that, or any, resource on the server. Conversely, a POST request is specifically for changing the state of a resource. So GET is for Query's and POST is for database changes.

Answer (score 0):

`request.method` tells you what http method is used for a request in the view. So you can code it accordingly.

e.g.

```
def my_view(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        #do processing for get

    else if request.method == 'POST':
        #do processing for POST

    ...
```

Comment: No. I don't think you understood my question. I would like to do both a GET and POST simultaneously.